# Number of submodules of the regular module for an abelian finite group.

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory, abelian-groups

I want to prove that if  There is a finite number of submodules of the regular module C[G] (where G is a finite group)  so G is an abelian group.
I'm thinking about using the Wedderburn theorem that says that C[G] a direct sum of subrepresentations of dimension 1, and all of them are simple but I dont know How to finish.
and if its abelian than the submodules are 1-dim , so I can sum up that the dissolution is single ?

Comment: I assume the statement you want to show is this: let $G$ be a finite group, then the regular module $\mathbb{C}G$ has finitely many submodules if and only if $G$ is abelian. The basic fact you need to answer this is that if $V$ is an irreducible representation of $G$, then there are exactly $\dim V$ isomorphic copies of $V$ sitting inside $\mathbb{C}G$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: can u please help me to solve it , I tried and I didnt find answer .